# Can't find data record in database table course_categories in moodle

Tags: moodle, moodle-theme

**[**I'm getting this error in my moodle**][1]**

And I can't go in any activity like security and any other activity so I can solve
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/83ofA.png

Comment: Can you please switch the debug level to developer in Moodle then copy and paste the error message into the question, not a screen shot.